# What do you call two people with opposite names?

Tags: american-english

What do you call two people with opposite names? Like:
Gonzales Fernando
And
Fernando Gonzales

I’ve been referring to them as Gängerdoppels in reference to Doppelgängers.

Comment: Could you please explain why anyone would need a word for such a pair of names?  The probability of such a thing is very high because many people have more than one forename name'  and many names can serve either as forename or surname.  The occurrence is too unsurprising for people to need a word for it.

Comment: At my work (250,000 employees) it causes a great deal of confusion when looking up a person to grant system access or find in an email lookup. I figured there would be a word I could use to bring attention to my work group about an individual with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English doesn't have a word for this.

The number of names which can be used in both positions is traditionally small, and even in this day and age when first names are more varied it's still uncommon. The likelihood of someone knowing both Leslie James and James Leslie is small, and having to use a word to refer to them both, as in "Here come the Gängerdoppels," is even less likely.

Words are coined and in general use when they are actually likely to be useful.

That said, your neologism *Gängerdoppel* might catch on, although it would probably give a German-speaker apoplexy.